# Modal - onChange event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, onchange

Trying to run the following test:
There are a few onChange events, and here is just one example. When I run the test, I keep getting the following error:

**Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**

Not sure if I am calling the state correctly. Or it might be a different approach since onChange event is located inside of a Modal.
Using Jest / Enzyme to test my files. (React JS)

Here is my DataFile.test.js

```
describe('Test', () => {
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><DataFile{...baseProps} /></BrowserRouter>));
```

```
it('Test onChange event on FirstName - Label', () => {
  baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
  wrapper.setState({
    quickFilterModalOpen: false,
    selectedQuickfilter: true,
    advancedFilter: {
      FirstName: 'test-FirstName',
    },
  });
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('input[id="fname-label-test"]').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test-FirstName' } });
  expect(wrapper.state().FirstName).toEqual('test-FirstName1');
});
```

Here is File.js Render method :

```
  <Modal isOpen={this.state.quickFilterModalOpen} style={descriptionModalStyle}>
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input
        id="fname-label-test"
        onChange={(e) => { this.setState({ advancedFilter: { ...this.state.advancedFilter, FirstName: e.target.value } }); }}
        value={this.state.advancedFilter.FirstName}
      />
    </div>
  </Modal>;
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.
Can you show us what is `wrapper` ?

Comment: @Alexandr added wrapper  on my test above ^^

Comment: What is `baseProps` ?

Comment: So the error is saying that there is no such element. `wrapper.find('input[id="fname-label-test"]')`  But I really not sure what is `Component`

Comment: where i passed all of this.props are declared. Example baseProps :{  location:[] , defaultdata{} , services:[]

Comment: @Alexandr updated once again

Comment: You need to check `DataFile` component. Does it even render your `Modal` component?

Comment: Yes, i run another test to render Modal  and i just check the snapshot, renders correctly